# PyPi-installed app fails with ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, pypi

I created a [project](https://github.com/valhuber/inheritance) that runs fine locally, but fails when run from PyPi deploy/install, with ModuleNotFound.  The link contains a very small sample, and run / deploy instructions.  My original thought was regarding inheritance, but it seems more basic.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/val/python/vscode/inheritance/venv/bin/inheritance-run", line 5, in <module>
    from inheritance.run import start
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inheritance'
```

Comment: You should add more details: e.g. which command did you run locally (successfully), what was the output, what command did you run that resulted in the error that you posted. 

Some context of what you are trying to do and what technology you are using would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup.py` has:

```
    packages=find_packages(),
```

This will find modules (directories with `__init__.py` files) in the same directory as your `setup.py` file, but you don't have any. Instead, you have a `base.py` file.

If you want to be able to `import inheritance`, you should move this into an `__init__.py` file in new directory named `inheritance`, so you have something like:

```
.
├── inheritance
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Then `setuptools` will find this module and include it as an importable package in your project.

FYI, It's usually preferable to use a `src`-based layout instead, however. See https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/ for a full example.

Comment: Restructured as recommended.

Still failing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'

See updated git at https://github.com/valhuber/inheritance